# Can we declare "How did this euphemism for a profanity originate?" as off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Growing up there were literally hundreds of different euphemisms we used when we could not swear.  They all seem to show up here in origin questions. Seeing as where they came from really is rarely relevant or documented can we just declare the entire genre off topic explicitly?

Answer (score 7):

I say no. Just because something is "rarely documented", it doesn't mean there won't be an interesting answer out there.